# Why no search result for the cjk(chinese) word in python's documentation generator--sphinx search bar?

Tags: python-3.x, search, python-sphinx

I build a simple project which contain only one article,the title is  `yahoo股票历史数据下载`,and the file `yahoo股票历史数据下载.rst`,only contain one sentence `问题:为何可以通过浏览器下载yahoo股票历史数据,无法使用wget curl下载?`
String in english can be searched.

[image]

To search cjk(chinese) word "股票" with grep command.

```
grep -n -r "股票"  myproject
/source/research/yahoo股票历史数据下载.rst:yahoo股票历史数据下载
/source/research/yahoo股票历史数据下载.rst:问题:为何可以通过浏览器下载yahoo股票历史数据,无法使用wget curl下载?
/build/html/research/yahoo股票历史数据下载.html:    <title>1. yahoo股票历史数据下载 &#8212; documents 1 documentation</title>
/build/html/research/yahoo股票历史数据下载.html:<h1>1. yahoo股票历史数据下载<a class="headerlink" href="#yahoo" title="Permalink to this headline">¶</a></h1>
/build/html/research/yahoo股票历史数据下载.html:<p>问题:为何可以通过浏览器下载yahoo股票历史数据,无法使用wget curl下载?</p>
/build/html/research/yahoo股票历史数据下载.html:<li class="toctree-l1 current"><a class="current reference internal" href="#">1. yahoo股票历史数据下载</a></li>
/build/html/research/yahoo股票历史数据下载.html:      <a href="../_sources/research/yahoo股票历史数据下载.rst.txt"
```

To search cjk(chinese) word "股票" in the python's documentation generator--sphinx search bar.
[image]

You can see that `yahoo` is the first word both in the title and in the content,the second word both in the title and in the content is the target `股票` to be searched.
Why your search did not match any documents?

Comment: What is your setting for `html_search_language` in your `conf.py`? Also search Sphinx's issue tracker for possible solutions: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/5605 and https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/4169

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install jieba lib.

```
sudo pip install jieba
```

To locate the jieba dictionary file.

```
sudo find /usr   -name  "jieba"
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jieba
ls  /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jieba
analyse     dict.txt  __init__.py  posseg
_compat.py  finalseg  __main__.py  __pycache__
```

The jieba dictionary file located in `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jieba/dict.txt`.

To edit sphinx's conf.py.

```
vim source/conf.py 
html_search_language = 'zh'
html_search_options = {'dict': '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jieba/dict.txt'}
```

To recompile all files in your project directory.

```
cd  yourproject
make html
```

To restart apache2.

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2 #maybe it is not neccessary.
```

Now chinese characters can be searched.